# BaseAdapter is sending wrong position? Android 2.3

Tags: android, google-play, baseadapter

I have a very strange problem in my navigation drawer.
I want to implement the navigation drawer like the one the Google Play Store has.

I've implement my navigation drawer in a base adapter but when I run my app in a emulator everythings looks fine when I open the navigation drawer, but when I click a item suddenly all items are mixed up(only on my android 2.3 device) The other one i;ve tested is a 4.4.2 Android device and everything works fine!

Code

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                context.getSystemService(ActionBarActivity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_item, null);
    }
    if (convertView != null) {
        //i//f(!(navDrawerItems.get(position).IsLoaded())) {
            //navDrawerItems.get(position).SetLoaded();
            ImageView imgIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            TextView txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            TextView txtCount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.counter);

            if (navDrawerItems.get(position).getIconVisibility()) {
                imgIcon.setImageResource(navDrawerItems.get(position).getIcon());
                txtTitle.setTextSize(20);
                //txtTitle.setMinHeight(20);
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams llp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                llp.setMargins(8, 0, 0, 0); // llp.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
                llp.height = 60;
                txtTitle.setLayoutParams(llp);
                convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.nav_little_border);
            } else {
                imgIcon.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }
            txtTitle.setText(navDrawerItems.get(position).getTitle());

            // displaying count
            // check whether it set visible or not
            if (navDrawerItems.get(position).getCounterVisibility()) {
                txtCount.setText(navDrawerItems.get(position).getCount());
            } else {
                // hide the counter view
                txtCount.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
      //  }

    }
```

I only want to show the icons for the last 2 items like (http://www.androidcentral.com/sites/androidcentral.com/files/styles/large_wm_brw/public/article_images/2014/04/Play-Movies-TV-sidebar.jpg?itok=qLSLoPNp)

Comment: what do you mean "mixed up"?

Comment: On the bottom there are 2 items with icons when I click on a item all items remove their icons.

Comment: But I'm switching to a navigation fragment and I am going to split the different items in two different list instead of control them with if else.